# Strongly typed Update and Create controller actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have example code in which the signature of the Create action menthod in the controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(JobCardViewData viewData)
```

I have just created a new MVC application and the same signature looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
```

I would prefer to know how to implement my action methods like the top example, or at least how to convert from the FormCollection to a business object without going as low level as using Reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I avoid using [`FormCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) as it is a collection of [*magic strings*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string_(programming)). I would recommend you to always use this signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(JobCardViewData viewData)
```

and leave the model binder do the job of parsing the request parameters into a strongly typed object (you don't need to resort to reflection or doing anything).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was so simple.